Astro JS with astro@i18next at <HeadHrefLangs /> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') at supportedLanguages.map
I am using Astro js With astro-i18next
I have correctly integrated at astro.config
import astroI18next from "astro-i18next";

// https://astro.build/config
export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [ tailwind(), 
    astroI18next(),
   ],
   output: 'server',
   adapter: vercel(),
});


//astro-i18next.config.mjs

/** @type {import('astro-i18next').AstroI18nextConfig} */
export default {
    defaultLocale: "en",
    locales: ["en", "zh-CN"],
    backend: {
        loadPath: "/locales/{{lng}}/{{ns}}.json", // Ensure this matches your file structure
      },
  }


I have prepared my Json file for both language & generated the page
& I am trying to import HeadHrefLangs component in my layout file
//Layout.astro

import i18next, { t } from "i18next";
import { HeadHrefLangs } from "astro-i18next/components";

<!doctype html>
<html lang={i18next.language}>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="description" content={description} />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/favicon.svg" />
    <meta name="generator" content={Astro.generator} />
    <title>{title}</title>
    <HeadHrefLangs />
  </head>

but getting this error


the error
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
at    supportedLanguages.map((supportedLanguage) => (

components/HeadHrefLangs.astro:10:19
---
import i18next from "i18next";
import { localizeUrl } from "../..";

const supportedLanguages = i18next.languages;
const currentUrl = Astro.url.href;
---

{
  supportedLanguages.map((supportedLanguage) => (

    <link
      rel="alternate"
      hreflang={supportedLanguage}
      href={localizeUrl(currentUrl, supportedLanguage)}
    />
  ))
}



Apparently i18next.languages returns undefined, not sure why. But if I were you, I'd use astro's built-in i18n features instead of that npm package. See e.g. https://docs.astro.build/en/recipes/i18n/

yes but I want to have a single Json file - which I can send for translation & auto page generation

Not sure I understand. What's not working for you with https://docs.astro.build/en/recipes/i18n/#translate-ui-strings ?

I fixed it by rolling back to older version, latest version has this bug, it works fine now

Just one more question If you can help would be amazing, It works good on localhost, but when I push to Vercel it doesn't translate translation, rather it just shows the id like home.banner.heading    if you can help in this would be of great help

Here's the link https://stackoverflow.com/q/79310236/10659230
