astro-i18next on Astro.js translation not working when pushed to Vercel
I built a astro site using astro-i18next for language conversion, I prepared my json file and It works perfectly on localhost,
But when I push it to Vercel for deployment the website works but the content in fields it should show from json file doesn't work.
E.g instead of Showing Heading it shows
home.banner.heading
Which is actually the key for that in json file ,
I tried searching everywhere about this issue but still no results.
I checked static files in Vercel built and that
/locales/en/translation.json
File does open with Vercel url and opens
But not sure why it's not working on Vercel website
Any help is appreciated, I am using latest version on astro-i18next
